# how to remove newline from a text file only if it does not match this pattern ]}\n in unix

Tags: regex, json, oracle, unix, sqlplus

i am new to oracle and unix world and struggling with this issue.
i am spooling data in a file. The sql plus has a linesize limit of 32767 and any data record returned greater than the limit gets wrapped into nextline. This file created is then uploaded to a third party service which is expecting data in a json format with a newline character only at the end ie after `}`

```
 {"id":"test","brand":"Disney","variants":[{"pid":"cup","name":"my cup"}]}
```

When there is a word wrap while spooling data a `\n` char is inserted between each line which is word wrapped and breaks this json data.

is there anyway i can escape control characters like `\n` in this spooled file only if it is not occurring after `}` ?
Can i use any unix command?

Any help will be appreciated

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Riffing off [this answer on a sister site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13681/33295), one you have your spooled file in Unix you can join lines together with `awk`:

```
awk '{if (sub(/\]}$/,"")) printf "%s]}\n", $0; else printf "%s", $0}' yourfile.lis
```

If you started with a file containing:

```
{"id":"test","brand":"Disney","variants":[{"pid":"cup","name":"my cup"}]}
{"id":"test","brand":"Disney","variants":[{"pid":"cup","name":"my
cup"}]}
{"id":"test","brand":"Disney","variants":[{"pid":"cup","name":"my cup"}
]}
{"id":"test","brand":"Disney","variants":[{"pid":"cup","name":"my cup"}]}
```

... where I'm faking that the second and third lines of your output has been split into two, with one split on an earlier `}`; that `awk` call would output:

```
{"id":"test","brand":"Disney","variants":[{"pid":"cup","name":"my cup"}]}
{"id":"test","brand":"Disney","variants":[{"pid":"cup","name":"my cup"}]}
{"id":"test","brand":"Disney","variants":[{"pid":"cup","name":"my cup"}]}
{"id":"test","brand":"Disney","variants":[{"pid":"cup","name":"my cup"}]}
```

And you can redirect that to a new file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. This solution is removing all newline characters but i want to remove only if newline character occurs between { }. How can i achieve that?

Comment: @user1633800 - not sure what you mean, this is only removing line breaks in the middle for me. The input and output in the answer were cut-and-paste from a Linux terminal. Are you saying you get the entire content of your files as one single long string?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much about your setup, one option is to pipe the file through a sed script like this:

```
cat input.txt | sed -e ':start; /^{.*]}$/{p;d}; N;s/\n//g; b start;' > output.txt
```

This basically works as follows:

1. **:start** creates a branch label to jump to
2. **/^{.*}$/{p;d}** find lines that start/end with curly braces, then prints them and moves on to the next line
3. **N** this only happens of the previous line did **NOT** get find a match, and reads the next line
4. **s/\n//g** removes all newlines (substitute them with nothing),
5. **b start** branches (jumps) back to the start label

In essence what it does is read a line, check that it starts and ends with curly braces.  If it does, print and move on.  If not, grab the next line.  This, of course, assumes that oracle will always output lines that start with { and end with } (i.e. no spaces before or after the braces).

Comment: You need to include the closing square bracket in the pattern, making it `/^{.*]}$/{s/\n//g;p;d}`, so it still works if the line happens to split on an earlier lone `}`.

Comment: @AlexPoole you are correct, however adding the ] case also resulted in the possibility of having a square brace, followed by a newline, then the curly brace `]\n}` so I had to move the newline substitution to the next line is appended.  This ensures no newlines in the pattern space.

I updated my solution above to reflect this.